# Tool to manage windows Programs using tags and images

Tags: windows, file-management, utility

Basically I am looking for something like steam, but for any program I decide to drop into it.

Requirements:
1) Needs to support exe and bat files (bare minimum).
2) Show list of program "icons"
3) Must be able to set icons manually
4) Support tagging/searching tags

Optional:
1) Should be portable (EG: work from an external drive that has all the programs installed to it)

I'm getting really sick of using simple windows folder hierarchy to sort things, and after a few hundred utilities/programs it becomes very unmanageable without remembering all the program names and what they do.

Basically windows shortcuts with custom icons, only with tagging and cleaner search.

Comment: This software would be great for organizing, tagging, and searching images or just about any other kind of file too.

Comment: I am using WinCatalog 2019, has everything I need. Supports tags/search/thumbnails, even lets you launch programs directly from the interface. Only downside is that I have to add programs one at a time. Although that's not really an issue for me, just means I have to spend some time adding all my programs and tagging them, which I was expecting to do anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify your OS so I'm finding Windows software for you.

1. This list of freeware [might help you](https://www.techsupportalert.com/content/best-free-file-disk-catalog-organizer.htm).
   What you want is disk or file cataloging software where you can enter a description (or hashtag in the desc field) for each file, then search on that desc field.
2. [Cathy](https://www.techsupportalert.com/content/cathy.htm-0) is an older software for Windows so not sure it is 32 bit yet. But I used it years ago and liked it.
3. Easy Disk Catalog, trialware. [Here](https://rbsoft.org/downloads/easy-disk-catalog-maker/).
4. A list of software from [Snapfiles](https://www.snapfiles.com/Freeware/system/fwdiskcat.html).
5. [WinCatalog 2019](https://www.wincatalog.com/free.html) looks promising and more modern. "While creating a catalogue of disks and files, you can efficiently organize it, using user defined fields, tags (categories) and virtual folders. You can set an automatic update of your file catalog, using Windows task scheduler." 30 day trial, personal license is $29.95usd.

Comment: OS:Windows 7 64 bit. I put windows in the tags but forgot to mention it in the main part.   
Do any of those suggestions support, displaying a custom thumbnail to represent a folder/disk/program? I am looking through them and will probably give most of them a try. Thanks for the suggestions!